# Docker-machine ip in Dockerfile

Tags: java, spring, docker, dockerfile

I have a Spring boot project with Docker. My Dockerfile like this:

```
...<many useful info>...
CMD ["java", "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<DOCKER_CONTAINER_IP>", "javafile.jar"]
```

I need set DOCKER_CONTAINER_IP (ip of docker container which I can get by `docker-machine ip default`) when I run Docker.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use environment variables.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables

```
docker run -e DOCKER_CONTAINER_IP=a.b.x.y mycontainer
```

If you need to specify them in your Dockerfile:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

```
FROM someimage
ENV DOCKER_CONTAINER_IP a.b.x.y
```

Comment: Additional you can use sub bash to get docker-machine ip 
`docker run -e DOCKER_CONTAINER_IP=$(docker-machine ip default) mycontainer`